# sed/grep tag of a commit in git

Tags: git, sed, grep, cut

I need to grep/sed tags that are associated for a commit in a git repository.

I have tried with this command:

```
git ls-remote -t <remote-project> | grep -E '<commit-sha>' | sed -e 's,.* -e refs/tags/,,' -e 's/\^{}//'
```

But what i get here is :

```
<commit-sha1> refs/tags/<tag1>
<commit-sha1> refs/tags/<tag2>
```

I want to fetch just tag1 and tag2 so that I can then seperate them and store it in variables for further usage.

I have also tried:

```
git ls-remote -t <remote-project> | grep -E '<commit-id>' | sed -e 's,.* -e refs/tags/,,' -e 's/\^{}//' | cut -f 2
```

Output:

```
refs/tags/<tag1>
refs/tags/<tag2>
```

Still not what I was looking for and i dont think it is the compact way of doing it.

Expected output for one commit:

```
tag1
tag2
```

Edit:

```
git ls-remote -t ssh://somerepo.git
```

This command gives me list of commits with associated tag information.

Output:

```
b63862c999a160add6b7617b3deb40a399aaa0e7    refs/tags/tag1
b63862c999a160add6b7617b3deb40a399aaa0e7    refs/tags/tag2^{}
1a761add5189d037e4b713a000aa650c740f624e    refs/tags/tag3
a8723b64a0d70f7d92ad65d3535ea13a9d6cfc2b    refs/tags/tag4^{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command

```
git ls-remote -t ssh://somerepo.git | sed  -n '/b63862c999a160add6b7617b3deb40a399aaa0e7/{s/.*\///p}'
```

or

```
git ls-remote -t ssh://somerepo.git | sed  -rn '/b63862c999a160add6b7617b3deb40a399aaa0e7/{s/.*\/([^^]+).*/\1/p}'
```

**First Command Output:**

```
tag1
tag2^{}
```

**Second Command Output:**

```
tag1
tag2
```

Comment: I dont see any output when I run this

Comment: can you share what is the output your getting while executing this  command `git ls-remote -t <remote-project>`

Comment: and also share  your expected result.

Comment: All the four sha's are different, how can we fetch tag1 and tag2 ?

Comment: Some of my commits have 2 or more tags associated with it.

Comment: See my update answers. I hope my answer may help your requirement